# Renaming Shared Documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-teams, modern-team-site

I'm struggeling with some employees in our company.
We have SharePoint Online with the latest OneDrive client. Somehow they managed to rename the Shared Documents folder on a team site to something else which breaks the connected Teams Team.

How can I rename it back so the connection to Teams is working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/09/sharepoint-online-change-list-document-library-url-using-powershell.html

The first part with adding the SPO as network adress helped. At that level I'm able to rename the *Shared Documents* folder back.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I changed the library name in UI as shown below:

[image]

Then I still can integrate with this library in Microsoft Teams.

Please check if the web address of the Shared documents has been modified:

[image]

If it is true, please open the site in SharePoint designer> All files> find the changed name and rename it to "Shared Documents".

---

---

[image]

Comment: I didn't manage to rename the default name, someone in our company did. And I have no clue who and how... :-|

Comment: Please check the updated reply.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the Designer and am not able to install it on my laptop.

Comment: First of all, whether the web address has been changed?please check it in browser address bar.